# why when i use modal fade as i suppose to it did not work?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been working with modal fade and it didn't work
what suppose happen is adding a new grade in partial view so i decided to work with modal fade and i didn't know anything about it.

so there is the code and please help me to fix the problem

```
<p>@* Button *@
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEdit(0)">New Grades</a>
</p>

<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Add/Edit Grades</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">

                <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
                    <img src="~/Image/load2.gif" width="150" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    var AddEdit = function (id) {
        var url = "/Grades/AddEditGrade/" + id;
        $("#myModalBodyDiv1").load(url, function () {
            $("mymodal1").modal("show");
        })
    }

</script>
```

any idea how can i fix it ??

Answer (score 0):

you are missing ID selector symbol in this line:

```
wrong: $("mymodal1").modal("show");
modified: $("#mymodal1").modal("show");
```